# Is there a resource that lists all the symbols HTML supports?

Tags: html

I'm simply trying to find a 'heavy downwards arrow' symbol. It seems that all the resources I've checked so far has iterations of this heavy arrow that point to the right and left, but not down. So I was wondering if there was some 'official' resource out there that has a full list of symbols supported in HTML? I would imagine something like this exists, just can't seem to find it.

Comment: You can literally use all of Unicode.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. My inexperience with HTML led me to searching for the wrong thing. What I did actually want was this list of characters/symbols supported in Unicode (which I was able to find). Thank you.

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/named-characters.html#named-character-references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about "official" per se, but I like to use [this site](http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/down%20arrow) to search for codes. For example, one such arrow might be the "downwards black arrow": `&#11015;` (⬇). There are other arrows you can search for if this one isn't the one you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Maybe this official resource isn't available, but this will definitely come in handy for what I'm trying to accomplish in case I need to find another symbol.

Comment: No worries. Might be TMI, and I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure that the HTML codes are Unicode conversions. So, the "official HTML symbol chart" might be better worded as the "official Unicode symbol chart". i.e. https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/unicode-characters.html

Answer (score 1):

Simply using a Search Engine gives the results you seek. The below resources were found in under 30 seconds. It is quicker for you to use a Search Engine than to actually write your Stack Overflow question!

## W3 Developer Listing (*The canon*):

https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

**Wikipedia:**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

**w3Schools:**

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_symbols.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_currency.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_arrows.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_symbols.asp

**And others:**

https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/symbols/

https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html

http://www.amp-what.com/

Comment: I've checked these resources already prior to posting. What I wanted to confirm was whether there was one resource that had an exhaustive list of all available symbols.