# How to get "<--" displayed in html so that the dashes are in the middle of the curve of the ''greater than'' symbol?

Tags: html, symbols

I am doing my first html homework and one of the requirements is to display the "greater than" sign in combo with two dashes within a linked text (as shown in the picture, hope you can see it).

[image]

Here's what it looks like for me:

[image]

Here is my code:

[image]

Comment: Add the CSS `font-family: "{{your favorite font here}}"`. Experiment with different fonts until you have one you like that aligns the characters how you want.

Comment: It will depend on the font. Is the character alignment really part of the requirements? That would make little sense. I'd just use `←` instead of `<--` and move on :)

Comment: @LionelRowe thank you, that's a good idea! Have not gotten to CSS yet, but this seems fairly easy to manage.

Comment: Well, it seems it is. Although, the ability to add the link itself might be more important :D. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

It mostly depends on the font sizes and line-heights, so I would say you use SVG icons for such manners. See [Material Icons](https://material.io/resources/icons/) for such manners. But if you want it in plain font as you have shown, you could use this CSS and HTML

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: fit-content;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<div onclick="Task1.html">
    <p style="margin: 0;">&lt;</p>
    <p style="margin: 0; margin-top: -2px;">--</p>
    <p style="margin: 0; margin-left: 8px">Back</p>
</div>
```

But I'm saying it again, I would never prefer this approach!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot! In my lessons it was never clarified how to add symbols in html in general, let alone any styling/borders etc. Thanks for the link as well :)! I will try out both of your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use your current textual method. Your course teacher is approximately 20 years out of date on how HTML elements are used now.

Instead using [HTML symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56408587/3536236) to draw a perfect arrow, in any font size and any line height.

```html
<div>
    <a href='Task1.html'>&larr; Back</a>
</div>
```

This is cleaner (both with CSS and HTML), simpler and always works across any browser and at any time.

There is a [huge list of possible HTML entities](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) you can use so you don't need to choose the same arrow I have used here for example.

If you want more complex glyphs (icons) then you can employ something called [**font-awesome**](https://fontawesome.com/) which has lots of these and has a free version. This system is already used by millions of websites. This uses CSS to load a custom font with custom shapes in it, for more complex things like "home" buttons, and envelopes, and big business brands, etc. etc.

Comment: he might be. He's out of date on VS Code too.  This looks much better and easier to read/implement. Thanks a lot :)!

Comment: @LieneLittlebird it is sadly very common for educators and education establishments to be extremely out of date on IT topics, because IT topics update and renew every 1-2 years whereas other education topics (Woodwork / Sciences / History) do not change much for decades or even centuries, the educators are not used to having to actually explore *and re-explore* best practise. So that you as the student are left in a tough situation; either do what your tutor expects, or do Best Practise. It's not a great choice and leads to many IT companies taking experience over grades every time. Good luck

Comment: thank you :)! Update - asked the teacher about these symbols - he just wrote everything in the text form and it somehow worked. It shouldn't, coz "<" is a tag border :D. My VS Code recognized the whole thing as a tag and added just the dashes. Screw this, many better symbols in the world :D.

Comment: @LieneLittlebird thanks for the feedback. Out of curiosity, does your teacher (so far) said anything about HTML5?

Comment: I'm not sure. The first lesson was quite a long time ago... Free courses though.